# ZedGraph XAxis on top of the graph rectangle

Tags: zedgraph

Is there a way to position the XAxis of the ZedGraph on top of the graph and use IsReverse on the scale of the YAxis so that my graph looks like below

```
  Y
X 0 1 2 3 4 5
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

Should I achieve this using X2 axis? I do not know how to add it if there is an X2Axis.

I have searched a lot and could not find an answer. Just wanted to make sure it is not possible before I switch to microsoft chart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using x2 axis by doing the following:

```
GraphPane.X2Axis.IsVisible = true;
GraphPane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = true;
```

Comment: what version has the X2 axis? I am using v5.0.1.25233 and it does not have X2. I will just get the latest one and try.

Comment: I've got 5.1.5.28844 which uses it, not sure but in previous versions you might be able to add an x axis using GraphPane.AddAxis

Comment: I have downloaded v5.1.5.28844 and I can get the X2Axis and everything works perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @cheedep No problem, I know how tough it can be to get ZedGraph help